# how to get sid in AWS S3 bucket policy in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

i want attaches a policy to an S3 bucket resource.

my terraform infra,

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "storage" {
  bucket = "${var.service}-${local.stage}-storage"
  acl    = "public-read"

  tags = {
    Service = var.service
    Stage   = local.stage
  }

  cors_rule {
    allowed_headers = [
      "*"
    ]
    allowed_methods = [
      "GET",
      "HEAD"
    ]
    allowed_origins = [
      "*"
    ]
    max_age_seconds = 3000
  }
}
```

this bucket for web static file hosting.i need bucket policy to public.

my policy in terraform,

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "storage-policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.storage.id

  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "????????",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "????????",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/*"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}
```

in this code, i need get Id, Sid field value.
how can i get this?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Id` and `Sid` are whatever you want. For example:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "storage-policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.storage.id

  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "my-bucket-polict",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "allow-all-access",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/*"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}
```